# Why dont show the right value in column with pandas in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bigdata

I try out some data analytics with pandas and got a problem.

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
path = "/PATH/TO/FILE/"
rnames = ["user_id", "movie_id", "rating", "timestamp"]
ratings = pd.read_csv(path + "ratings.csv", engine="python", sep=",", header=0, names=rnames)
mnames = ["movie_id", "title", "genres"]
movies = pd.read_csv(path + "movies.csv", engine="python", sep=",", header=0, names=mnames)
print(ratings[:5])
print(movies[:5])
print(movies.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
user_id  movie_id  rating   timestamp
0        1        31     2.5  1260759144
1        1      1029     3.0  1260759179
2        1      1061     3.0  1260759182
3        1      1129     2.0  1260759185
4        1      1172     4.0  1260759205
movie_id      ...   genres
0         1   ...   Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
1         2   ...   Adventure|Children|Fantasy
2         3   ...   Comedy|Romance
3         4   ...   Comedy|Drama|Romance
4         5   ...   Comedy
[5 rows x 3 columns]
movie_id     int64
title       object
genres      object
dtype: object

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The movies.csv is from [Movielens](http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-latest-small.zip) and looks like this:

```
movieId,title,genres
1,Toy Story (1995),Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
2,Jumanji (1995),Adventure|Children|Fantasy
3,Grumpier Old Men (1995),Comedy|Romance
4,Waiting to Exhale (1995),Comedy|Drama|Romance
5,Father of the Bride Part II (1995),Comedy
```

As you can see the title won`t show correctly (... instead of the title).

Can someone help me, please? :)

Comment: I think, there is no problem. Print function could not fit the data into line space. You can print the pandas DataFrame ( `pd.read_csv` returns DataFrame) with `ratings.head(5)` and `movies.head(5)`

Comment: I tried, but the same result.  If I do it with another csv file like movies2.csv and the 2nd value is just "Toy", I got the same result.

Comment: pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)  
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', -1)
That worked for me...thanks for the other topic :)